# AD-HOC edit /etc/sudoers from Ansible server side

Tags: linux, ansible, privileges, sudoers, ansible-ad-hoc

I'm trying to add privilege to Ansible node via Ansible server using "lineinfile" via ad-hoc command as ROOT :

```
ansible -i rec-apache.inv -m lineinfile -a "path=/etc/sudoers \
line ='ansible-node1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) NO PASSWD:ALL'" --become-method=su --become -K all
```

I got the following error

```
ERROR! this task 'lineinfile' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules:
shell, win_shell, include_vars, add_host, raw, include_role, meta, set_fact, include, 
import_tasks, script, import_role, include_tasks, group_by, command, win_command
```

I already did the key exchange and everything went good and right . This problems occurs only when I use root user in the server side.
I know that I can do it using playbook ,but I'm interesting on the ad-hoc command. Thank you !

Comment: Try without a space after `line` e.g.: `line='ansible-node1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) NO PASSWD:ALL'`?

Answer (score 0):

A space after line in `line ='...'` might have cause Ansible to treat `='...'` as a parameter, which is not supported. Try removing the space as: `line='ansible-node1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) NO PASSWD:ALL'`